# Grails: how can I customize the location of the .slcache directory? [Can't do it, Bug raised]

Tags: grails

Currently the .slcache directory lives at `%USER_HOME%\.grails\.slcache` and has around 12M of data in it. I work in a restricted corporate environment and this causes me problems with my windows profile allocations (which sadly, I am unable to change).

I have managed to move the ivy-cache and other contents of the .grails dir by adding the following in my BuildConfig.groovy:

```
grails.work.dir="c:/.grails"
grails.project.dependency.resolution = {
    cacheDir "c:/grails-ivy-cache"
}
```

But I can't find out how to customize the location of .slcache

Using Grails 2.0.0 M2

Comment: Have you tried simply removing it?  It doesn't seem to be necessary.  I do have that directory on my computer as well, but I renamed it to no ill effect, and it wasn't recreated.  I can't find a reference to that directory anywhere in Grails 1.3.7 or the source for Grails 2.

Comment: @OverZealous - I did remove it a couple of times, but it kept coming back when I restarted ... Have a look at (http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-7782) ... Yeah, I've grepped around in the source, too - I wonder how they refer to it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The slcache is used by the reloading agent to cache reload information. So it is definitely necessary. Deleting it might result in strange reloading errors. Currently there is no open to customize it, but please feel free to raise a JIRA at http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS

Comment: Interesting.  Would it be safe to delete on a development machine?  (Say, when the application is not actively running?)

Comment: Thanks @GraemeRocher, I've raised a jira http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-8059 to get the ability to customize the location of this directory into the plans.